# Saving RGB matrix as text

Tags: python, opencv, matrix, rgb

I tried to save an RGB matrix in text format but without success. The resolution of the image is 640 x 480. I'm looking for matrix with 640 columns and 480 rows and for every element the corresponding RGB value. For example:

```
(230, 200, 20) (130, 11, 13) ... # and the others 658 columns
(200, 230, 20) (11, 130, 13) ... 
... # and the others 478 rows
```

Comment: What format is the data in right now? Are you starting with a PNG file, say, or do you already have a 640 x 480 x 3 array?

Comment: I've images in jpeg format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's the exact output you want, then I think this does the job. You can use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) to get whatever you need.

```
# Read the image file.
from scipy import misc
data = misc.imread('image.jpg')

# Make a string with the format you want.
text = ''
for row in data:
    for e in row:
        text += '({}, {}, {}) '.format(e[0], e[1], e[2])
    text += '\n'

# Write the string to a file.
with open('image.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Note that some image types (e.g. PNG) commonly contain four values per pixel, because they can have an 'alpha' (opacity) channel.

Comment: It's exactly what I want! Thank you Mr. Kwinkunks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using scipy and numpy, and do something like this (untested)

```
from scipy import misc
import numpy
data = misc.imread('img1.png')
numpy.savetxt('out.txt', data)
```

Comment: It doesn't work: TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('uint8') and format specifier ('%.18e %.18e %.18e...)

Comment: Try numpy.savetxt('out.txt', data, fmt="%s")