# Copy each row in a pandas data.frame to individual files

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have been trying to save each row of a data.frame in a file named as the index of that specific row.

The structure of the data.frame is basically this:

```
SUBMITTED_ID    SYMBOL  IMMUNE  CLASS   CELL_HUM    LOCATION_ARM    LOCATION_MIN    LOCATION_MAX
FBgn0000047  Act88F     control control control 3R  15439969    15442177
FBgn0000094  Anp    immunity    humoral AMP 3R  30209948    30210382
FBgn0000116  Argk   control control control 3L  9048781 9066027
```

What I've got so far is this:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1])
df['NAME']= df['SUBMITTED_ID']+'-'+df['SYMBOL']+'-'+df['IMMUNE']+'-'+df['CLASS']+'-'+df['CELL_HUM']
df_indexed = df.set_index('NAME')
df_bed =df_indexed[['LOCATION_ARM','LOCATION_MIN','LOCATION_MAX']]
for index, row in df_bed.iterrows():
    np.savetxt(str(index)+'.bed', row, delimiter='\t', fmt="%s")
```

It works, but it's saving each value of the row in separate lines, like this:

```
3R
22034298
22038925
```

Does somebody have any idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you,

Murillo

Comment: Try using fmt="%s" in np.savetxt() perhaps? (from http://stackoverflow.com/a/33757983/2997179)

Comment: That worked, thanks! But now I have the following problem: it's not saving the entire row delimited by tabs, but instead each value in each line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need index, first [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), convert to `ndarray` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and then use [`tofile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html):

```
for row in df_bed.reset_index().values:
    #print row
    row[1:].tofile(str(row[0])+'.bed', sep="\t", format="%s")
```

Comment: That's almost good enough! But I needed the files to be named as the index of that row.

Comment: The name of the file is OK, but now the index is also inside the file and I don't want that: FBgn0283461-Drs-immunity-humoral-AMP 3L 3369556 3369942

Comment: Thanks for the help so far!!